# Someone that ignores others but hates being ignored themselves

Tags: single-word-requests

I know this person that common courtesy doesn't apply to. If I don't reply to a text or a missed call from them within 5 minutes, it's always quickly followed by another 10-15 texts or calls one after another. When I text them, it could take up to 2 days to a week to reply (usually when they want something).

If they post something on Facebook and nobody comments, they lose their mind. When I share some really good news to them, I get nothing; not even a congratulations, good job or anything.

Comment: If you're looking for a word to describe that person, "dick", I believe, will do quite well.

Comment: Bahahaha! That does describe her quite well sometimes. Thank u. That made me smile

Answer (score 1):

You might say that they were **[self-absorbed](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/self%E2%80%93absorbed)**

> only caring about and interested in yourself

Answer (score 1):

A ***narcissist***, perhaps (a person characterised by excessive self-love or vanity; self-admiration, self-centredness (OED)).

Answer (score 0):

Consider '[egocentric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egocentrism)'?

> A person who is egocentric believes they are the center of attention

Comment: Yeah, thats a good word but im not qute sure. Anything else? She gives the impression she cares but not really.

Comment: @bobmacgyver I'm sorry I don't understand. Does she care or does she pretend to care? Does she care about other people or only care about being ignored? If she only cares about being ignored, and only pretends to care about other people, egocentric still fits.

Comment: Judging from her actions I believe she pretends to care about others and definitely cares when she gets ignored herself. But yes, u r right.egocentric does fit. But I was thinking "narcissistic". What do u think? thanx spagirl

Comment: @bobmacgyver I think narcissistic is probably appropriate for what you describe. My only reservation about either of them is that they carry a hint of medical diagnosis about them.

Answer (score 0):

You could say that they are an [**attention seeker**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/attention-seeking)

> Attempting to attract the attention of other people, typically by disruptive or excessively extrovert behaviour:

*Oxford Dictionaries*